# Confusion over SDL_SetSurfaceAlphaMod

Tags: sdl-2

I've read the documentation on SDL_SetSurfaceAlphaMod. Although the alpha modulation formula looks very straightforward, I can't predict the results of using it in code. Clearly my understanding is incomplete.

To clarify my thinking, I've written a piece of code (see below). **The idea is to put four black squares on a red background, in two rows of two.**

The top two squares are black, because that is what a surface created using SDL_CreateRGBSurface defaults to. SDL_FillRect is not used.

The bottom two squares use SDL_FillRect to set them to black after they are created (even though they would be black anyway).

The squares on the left have an alpha modulation value of 0.

The squares on the right have an alpha modulation value of 255.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    SDL_Window * windowMain;
    SDL_Surface * surfaceMain;
    Uint32 rmask, gmask, bmask, amask;

    // Main window suface - red background
    windowMain = SDL_CreateWindow("Test Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 480, 360, 0);
    surfaceMain = SDL_GetWindowSurface(windowMain);
    Uint32 redBG = SDL_MapRGB(surfaceMain->format, 255, 0, 0);
    SDL_FillRect(surfaceMain, NULL, redBG);

#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
    rmask = 0xff000000;
    gmask = 0x00ff0000;
    bmask = 0x0000ff00;
    amask = 0x000000ff;
#else
    rmask = 0x000000ff;
    gmask = 0x0000ff00;
    bmask = 0x00ff0000;
    amask = 0xff000000;
#endif

    SDL_Surface * noFillSquare = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 100, 100, 32, rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);
    SDL_Surface * blackFillSquare = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 100, 100, 32, rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);
    Uint32 blackFG = SDL_MapRGB(blackFillSquare->format, 0, 0, 0);
    SDL_FillRect(blackFillSquare, NULL, blackFG);

    while (true)
    {
        showSurface(noFillSquare, surfaceMain, 0, 0, 100, 50); // Top left rectangle
        showSurface(noFillSquare, surfaceMain, 255, 0, 300, 50); // Top right rectangle (not displayed)
        showSurface(blackFillSquare, surfaceMain, 0, 0, 100, 200); // Bottom left rectangle
        showSurface(blackFillSquare, surfaceMain, 255, 0, 300, 200); // Bottom right rectangle

        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(windowMain);
    }

    return 1;
}

void showSurface(SDL_Surface * srcSurface, SDL_Surface * dstSurface, Uint8 srcAlpha, Uint8 dstAlpha, int x, int y)
{
    SDL_Rect rect = { x, y, srcSurface->w, srcSurface->h };
    SDL_SetSurfaceAlphaMod(srcSurface, srcAlpha);
    SDL_SetSurfaceAlphaMod(dstSurface, dstAlpha);
    SDL_BlitSurface(srcSurface, NULL, dstSurface, &rect);
}
```

Running the code results in the display:

[Display from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDJrB.png)

As you can see, the top right black square is not shown.

**I would like to request a step-by-step breakdown as to why that one square doesn't appear, while the other three do.**

I'm finding SDL 2.0 documentation to be quite sketchy, especially when it comes to surfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overwrote SDL 2.0.9 include files and libraries with 2.0.10 versions and the problem immediately went away.

I now get the expected output.

[The correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoadE.png)

Not really sure what was wrong before - some mismatched library files perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

When creating surfaces, SDL does `memset(0)` on pixels array. It indeed results in black colour, but alpha becomes 0 too - which is fully transparent. Multiplying 0 by alpha modifier still results in 0.

FillRect replaces alpha with fully opaque colour because you use `SDL_MapRGB` and not e.g. `SDL_MapRGBA` with 0 alpha.

Comment: "Multiplying 0 by alpha modifier still results in 0." Absolutely - but both squares on the top row were created that way, so I would expect the same thing to happen to both of them. Why does changing the alpha modifier alter their visibility?

Comment: I see what you mean. What OS/renderer/SDL version we're talking about? Is code in question contains everything you have? It sure shows only last rectangle for me, as it should be.

Comment: I'm not using a software renderer - you've got all my code, apart from two lines at the top: the showSurface() function prototype and the include for SDL.h. I'm using Windows 10, but I could check this code on my WinXP setup. I'm worried now that I've got some dodgy version of SDL 2.0 - will check the version.

Comment: I'm using SDL 2.0.9.

Comment: I cut and pasted the above code straight into a test project on my WinXP machine - and got the exact same weird output.as from Win10. SDL 2.0.9 in both cases

Comment: Can't reproduce. Why not 2.0.10 though?

Comment: I read about people running into bugs going from 2.0.9 to 2.0.10, but perhaps it will work the other way for me! So you only see the bottom right square?

Comment: Yes only last square is opaque. Tried with different renderer impl, on different SDL versions, etc. - always consistent. Haven't tested on 32bit though.

Comment: I suppose it could be a 32 vs 64 bit issue - I'll look into it and report back. Thanks for providing your time and expertise keltar.